# Iterate Cartesian product

Tags: javascript, iteration, cartesian-product, for-comprehension

Until recently, I used the ancient coding style like

```
        for (var i in list) for (var j in list)
            connect(list[i], list[j])
```

Things have changed once I have realized that I can forEach since JS6

```
    () => list.forEach(i => list.forEach(j => connect(i,j)))
```

I wonder if there is further syntax to optimize the latter into

```
    () => (list, list).forEach((i,j) => connect(i,j))
```

Comment: `(list, list)` returns just `list`, respecting the comma operator.

Comment: And what? Do you say that it means that there is no hope for iterating multidimentional constructions?

Comment: sorry, i do not say something other. you need still some nested structure for it.